# Entity-Framework InvalidCastException

Tags: entity-framework

This code compiles but generates a run-time error. Essentially, I'm simply executing a stored proc in entity-framework and attempting to return a single object. Any ideas on w

CODE:

```
 public static TowingCustomerVehicle GetTowingCustomerVehicle(int vehicleID)
        {
            using (ProductServiceEntities context = new ProductServiceEntities())
            {
                TowingCustomerVehicle vehicle = (TowingCustomerVehicle)context.Vehicles
                      .Where(v => v.VehiclePK == vehicleID)
                      .Select(v => new TowingService2._0.Model.Towing.TowingCustomerVehicle
                      {
                            CurbWeight = (int)v.CurbWeight,
                            HitchSystemRating = (int)v.TowingCapacityMaximum,
                            FuelType = v.FuelType,
                            TopType = v.TopType,
                            TongueLoadRating = (v.TowingCapacityMaximum ?? 0),
                            IsCVT = v.IsAutoTransCVT ?? false,
                            DriveType = v.Driveline,
                            EPAClass = v.EPAClass,
                            Make = v.Make,
                            Model = v.Model
                      });

                vehicle.AttachedWiring = context.IsAttachedWiring(vehicleID).Count() > 0 ? true : false;


                return vehicle;
            }
        }
```

ERROR:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[TowingService2._0.Model.Towing.TowingCustomerVehicle]' to type 'TowingService2._0.Model.Towing.TowingCustomerVehicle'.

Answer (score 1):

Select returns an `IEnumerable<TowingCustomerVehicle>`. You need to add `.First()` to the end of the select call.

```
TowingCustomerVehicle vehicle = context.Vehicles
                  .Where(v => v.VehiclePK == vehicleID)
                  .Select(v => new TowingService2._0.Model.Towing.TowingCustomerVehicle
                  {
                        CurbWeight = (int)v.CurbWeight,
                        HitchSystemRating = (int)v.TowingCapacityMaximum,
                        FuelType = v.FuelType,
                        TopType = v.TopType,
                        TongueLoadRating = (v.TowingCapacityMaximum ?? 0),
                        IsCVT = v.IsAutoTransCVT ?? false,
                        DriveType = v.Driveline,
                        EPAClass = v.EPAClass,
                        Make = v.Make,
                        Model = v.Model
                  }).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see rhe result is of type `ObjectQuery<TowingCustomerVehicle>`, and you need one item of type `TowingCustomerVehicle` from that query. Add `First()` at the end or `FirstOrDefault()`. You won't need the cast after that.

Haven't tried this on in VS to see if it compiles but it should work fine.

Hope it helps.